# Facebook Page not displaying on mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile

Does anyone know why when I load this page Facebook page on my Android phone
http://www.facebook.com/LoveMyPhilly#!/LoveMyPhilly?sk=app_7146470109

It just brings me to the lovemyphilly wall?

Does touch.facebook support Facebook Pages?

Answer (score 0):

mobile versions of websites are usually stripped down to not include extra things like this.

going to the mobile version of the site at http://m.facebook.com/LoveMyPhilly?sk=app_7146470109, it instantly takes you to the wall. doesnt look like its accessable